# Make <div> scale to content when absolutely positioned?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

Usually a `<div>` will expand to fill content insize.

```
<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

The `<div>` scales to contain the `<p>`

Is it possible to make the `<div>` do this when it's absolutely positioned?

In my case I have a modal which has a set height and width, but I want to make it scale to the content.

Comment: Actually it's the opposite in your example. Both the `div` and `p` has `width: auto` by default. The `div` will expand to use the full width of the parent element, then the `p` will expand to use the full width of the `div`. When you use absolute positioning the `div` is taken out of the flow, so there is no parent element to get the size from.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/3L99pycm/

CSS:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
}
p {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

div behave the same independently from its position, most likely the problem is that you are setting a fixed size parameter somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Well You dont need to do anything special to make the absolute div scale to the child. I added an example here http://jsfiddle.net/rtkvswmn/

CSS

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
}
p{
    width: 100px;
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
```